# Create elementor plugin extension for new structure same as column widget

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor

I want to create elementor plugin extension for new structure same as column widget which can allow adding other widgets inside it.
**I need new different structure apart of elementor column structure.**
I have referred below URL for creating widget but it can create the only widget, not section.
Referred URL:- https://developers.elementor.com/creating-an-extension-for-elementor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom plugin which will extend the functionalities of the existing plugin or you can able to create your own functionality.

```
<?php
class Elementor_Test_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {}

    public function get_title() {}

    public function get_icon() {}

    public function get_categories() {}

    protected function _register_controls() {}

    protected function render() {}

    protected function _content_template() {}

}



Widget Name – The get_name() method is a simple one, you just need to return a widget name that will be used in the code.
Widget Title – The get_title() method, which again, is a very simple one, you need to return the widget title that will be displayed as the widget label.
Widget Icon – The get_icon() method, is an optional but recommended method, it lets you set the widget icon. you can use any of the eicon or font-awesome icons, simply return the class name as a string.
Widget Categories – The get_categories method, lets you set the category of the widget, return the category name as a string.
Widget Controls – The _register_controls method lets you define which controls (setting fields) your widget will have.
Render Frontend Output – The render() method, which is where you actually render the code and generate the final HTML on the frontend using PHP.
Render Editor Output – The _content_template() method, is where you render the editor output to generate the live preview using a Backbone JavaScript template.
```

The Widget_Base class has many more methods you can use to do different things but for now, this should be good enough.

**Sample of Widget**

```
<?php

use Elementor\Widget_Base;

class Elementor_oEmbed_Widget extends Widget_Base {


public function get_name() {
    return 'oembed';
}


public function get_title() {
    return __( 'oEmbed', 'plugin-name' );
}


public function get_icon() {
    return 'fa fa-code';
}

/* categories. */
public function get_categories() {
    return [ 'general' ];
}


protected function _register_controls() {

    $this->start_controls_section(
        'content_section',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-name' ),
            'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
        ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
        'url',
        [
            'label' => __( 'URL to embed', 'plugin-name' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'input_type' => 'url',
            'placeholder' => __( 'https://your-link.com', 'plugin-name' ),
        ]
    );

    $this->end_controls_section();

}


protected function render() {

    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

    $html = wp_oembed_get( $settings['url'] );

    echo '<div class="oembed-elementor-widget">';

    echo ( $html ) ? $html : $settings['url'];

    echo '</div>';

}

}
```

Comment: I'm currently facing a similar issue, but I fail to see how this answers the part of the question relevant to me.


As stated here "which can allow adding other widgets inside it"


Perhaps I assumed OP meant other Elementor widgets, or I misunderstand how wp_oembed_get works here. But it seems that this extension of the widget with the wp_oembed_get doesn't allow for a user to drag another widget into my own plugin generated widget.

Comment: @MostafaElBeheiry Would you please explain what you would like to buid? Are you creating new Elementor widget? ABove code will help you to create your own Elementor Widget then you can drag and drop like other Elementor widget into your project. I have created my own extension plugin for Elementor please take a look : https://wordpress.org/plugins/extensions-for-elementor/

Comment: Then I must have some issue with my implementation, I'll give it another shot with your link, thanks!

Just to reiterate, I made a simple carousel plugin (Or elementor widget rather) and I want to add an inner section into it. Which other Elementor users can simply drag other Elementor widgets into. So my own plugin has to be able to accept the draggable elements. If that's what the above code does, then I'm sure I mis-implemented it along the way. Thanks for the reply regardless!

Comment: Just a follow-up: If I'm not misunderstanding this thread: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/4070 This seems as though it's not yet doable within Elementor, I already have my widget working I just wanted to get it more customizable. Oh well, I'll resort to more creative workarounds until hopefully we get this feature.

Comment: @MostafaElBeheiry As per my knowledge we can create any kind of structure with existing Elementor capability and if we not then we can create widget easily as per our requirement.  There is already a inner section widget available which help us to create any complex structure of site. You can also use free templates and other free extensions available to boost your development. Hope that solves your concerns.

Comment: Completely correct, when discussing issues about an entire website / page. Like I said, I made my own custom widget, and I want it to be able to accept an elementor inner section. This is different from creating any kind of structure on a whole page. I did not say I wanted to recreate the inner section widget, I wanted to be able to add it (or any other) to an existing custom widget. Which as the issue above shows, seems currently out of reach. Or at the very least not easily available. But thanks for the offer & insight at any rate!